# How to convert newlines to proper JSON in GO?

Tags: json, string, go, string-literals

I have some strings that I'd like to convert to JSON. Using encoding/json here, haven't tried other packages.

The strings may contain newlines and other stuff that breaks JSON if saved as-is.

It works if I pass a string literal - it adds backslashes in front of backslashes. It doesn't work if I just pass a regular string. I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to use variables that contain string literals.

edit: as pointed out, these are not the same values and I kind of understand that, but it doesn't help me solve my problem.

The sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    type Test struct {
        Input string
    }
    regularString := Test{"asd\nqwe"}
    out, err := json.Marshal(regularString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))

    literalString := Test{`asd\nqwe`}
    out, err = json.Marshal(literalString )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

Comment: What is the output you expect in your sample? If it makes it clearer, I've added a couple of extra `Println`s that show the strings being encoded in the go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Kk4wtaUBW9A). Note the first has an actual new line, the second has a \n which will be encoded as \\n in json to prevent it being interpreted as a new line.

Answer (score 2):

The `encoding/json` properly encodes all string values.

Your first example works as you expect it because you use an *interpreted string literal*, and if that contains a `\n` sequence, the compiler will replace that with a newline character.

Your second example doesn't work as you expect it because you used a *raw string literal*, which if contains a `\n` sequence, that will not be replaced, but those 2 characters will remain in the string. And that will be escaped by `encoding/json` properly to remain that in the JSON outpupt.

So basically

```
"asd\nqwe"`
```

and

```
`asd\nqwe`
```

are 2 different strings, they are not equal, hence their JSON escaped values are also different.

Check [Spec: String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) for more details.

Note that if you want to create a string value using a raw string literal, you can't use escape sequences in it. To have a newline in a raw string literal, simply break the line, like this:

```
s := `asd
qwe`
```

Another option is to "break" the string literal, and insert the newline using an interpreted string literal (and concatenate the parts):

```
s := `asd` + "\n" + `qwe`
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense.How can I make it work though?

Comment: @LauriK: What's not working?  You demonstrated that it works with `"`.

Comment: @LauriK Yes, it _is_ working. If you want the string to contain a newline, use a string value that contains a newline and not a backslash followed by an `n` character.

Comment: @LauriK Added examples how you can include newline in a raw string literal.